# XCode compile error: confirmationDialog is only available IOS 15.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm an apprentice of Swift language and having an online course with tutorials.

While I was coding along with the instructor there was this "confirmationDialog is only available IOS 15.0 or newer." error presented. I had to write`if #available(iOS 15.0, *)` as compiler suggested.  However the instructors compiler did not present the same error and she did not make any changes on her code.

My question is that why the above mentioned error occured on my compiler but not on the instructors? and how can I get rid of this error without adding `if #available(iOS 15.0, *)`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: change the minimum ios target to IOS 15

Comment: There is no iOS symbol called `comfirmationDialog` so either you are not reporting accurately or you're not giving the whole story.

Comment: @matt https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:)-9ibgk

Comment: @jnpdx spelled differently, so my first option is correct. And the OP did not tag for SwiftUI so my second option is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference in your environment vs your instructors is that your instructor has their "deployment target" set to iOS 15 and yours is set to something lower like iOS 14 or 13. The deployment target setting governs the minimum version of iOS that your app is allowed to run on. Your instructor's app can only run on iOS 15 and later, so they don't need to use `if #available(iOS 15.0, *)`. This condition would always be true for them. In your case, since your app supports iOS 14, there are some scenarios where the `confirmationDialog` API will not be available to the user (since it was added in iOS 15), which is why you need the check. If you are okay with using a minimum version of iOS 15 like your instructor, you can change this setting in Xcode. Click your project name in the project navigator, click your app target, then click the "General" tab. You should see an area called "Deployment Info" and a dropdown for the iOS version. Change this to iOS 15.